# Multiuser database, how to identify, when a client disconnected

Tags: java, database, h2

I am using H2 Database for a retail POS software developed in Java Swing. I have an issue, in multiuser environment, where few clients connected to the server.

If a client system exits abnormally and tries to reconnect again, how the server can identify it and reconnects again.? Is there any method to identify, immediately after a client get disconnected.

It will be a great help for me. Thanks in advance.

With kind regards,

I.Murugesan
yuvapos@gmail.com

Comment: So you want the server to identify the client connects? Why?

Comment: To enable the same client to connect again. Otherwise, when a client exits abnormally, since the server didn't know this, the server will not allow the same client to log again.

Comment: The H2 TCP Server will not prevent a user to log in multiple times concurrently. If you want this feature, you will need to implement it yourself. But I have added an answer that might help (see below).

Answer (score 0):

For each database, there is a table `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SESSIONS`. You can use it to list all open session for a database.

Also, there is an in-memory "management_db_" for each TCP server. A TCP server can server multiple databases. To connect to it, you need to know the `managementPassword`, which is the password you need to set using the `-tcpPassword` setting. The user name is an empty string. See also [`TcpServer.initManagementDb` and `TcpServer.shutdown`](http://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/server/TcpServer.java). You can get the sessions, database URLs, user names, and time of connection (the table name is `sessions`).

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I thinks I can solve my problem. Is it possible to grant all to all tables ?

Comment: Do you mean grant a user access to all tables in the database? The only shortcut I know is to [create an admin user](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_user).